# qsub job array (-t), wait finish previews task

Tags: arrays, linux

"Linux Server"

I have this code

```
for i in *.sh; do echo "bash $i ZMV" | qsub -N ZMV -t 1-7 -cwd -l h_vmem=2G; done
```

The point is that I don't want to start all qsub together but one by one (the second after the first finished, the third when the second finished)

In a "normal" situation (without -t), I use -hold_jid but in this case I don't know what to do.

Comment: Please, someone could give me at least an input... thanks

Answer (score 0):

The qsub switch "-tc" is supposed to control the maximum number of concurrent jobs.

I think you want to add "-tc 1" to your qsub command line.